# Is it possible to export data rows including image per row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, image, csv, export

I have a Rails 5.2 application.
There I have a user model, and each user have their profile image. Now what I need to achieve is, I need to export multiple users in a excel/csv file.

One user will have one row, with column containing their detail. Like Id, Name, Email, Address, Contact, ProfileImage.

I was able to export all other data except image. I was able to figure out a way to export single image per sheet but, I am stuck with image per row.

Currently I have removed all my changes regarding csv related gem usages and image, because i wasn't getting any where

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
    attributes = %w{id name email address contact}
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
        csv << attributes
        User.all.each do |user|
            csv << [user.id, user.name, user.email, user.address, user.contact]
        end
    end
end
```

I know I need something like caxlsx, but still clueless and unable to figureout how to proceed.
All the excel export gems have example to export single image per sheet.
Anything regarding this will be really helpful
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

## So, this is for all those who are facing this same issue, or doing this for first time.

I am using `'caxlsx_rails'` as my Spreadsheet generator.

First, **Issue** I don't know why image is not loading in Microsoft excel in windows 10. I have tested on google sheet, but this solution is working for it.
I saw an open issue regarding this image not rendering issue on git. Hopefully it will get fixed.
So I am posting partially working solution.

### In GemFile

```
    gem 'caxlsx'
    gem 'caxlsx_rails'
```

### in controller

```
    def export_data
        render xlsx: 'export_data', template: 'some_view_path/export_data.xlsx.axlsx', 
        filename: "data_#{DateTime.now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")}.xlsx", disposition: 'inline'
    end
```

### in view, template for xlsx

```
    ## some_view_path/export_data.xlsx.axlsx
    wb = xlsx_package.workbook # create excel book

    wb.add_worksheet(name: "Data Sheet Name") do |sheet|
        header = wb.styles.add_style({:alignment => {:horizontal => :center, :vertical => 
        :center, :wrap_text => true}, :border => { :style => :thin, :color => "000000" }}) 
        border = wb.styles.add_style({:border => { :style => :thin, :color => "000000" }}) 
        align_right = wb.styles.add_style({:alignment => {:horizontal => :right}}) 
        align_left = wb.styles.add_style({:alignment => {:horizontal => :left}})
   
        sheet.add_row
        ## empty row
    
        sheet.add_row ["Data1", "Data2", "Data3" , "Data4" , "Image"], style: header
    
        Model.all.each do |obj|
            row = sheet.add_row [obj.data1, obj.data2, obj.data3, obj.data4], height: 100
            index = row.row_index + 1
            # this is just to point out where to display image
            start_at = "E#{index}"
            # image header/column is on E
            img = obj.images.first
            # if you hae multiple image you can get all and display them accordingly,
            # here i am only taking first one, as it satisfies my requirement.
            path = ActiveStorage::Blob.service.send(:path_for, img.key)
            # getting actual location for activeStorage file,
            # if you have image file location, you can point it directly
            sheet.add_image(image_src: path, start_at: start_at, width: 100, height: 100)
            # adding image
        end
    end
```

button to download excel file

### in some view

```
    <%= link_to "Export Sample", export_sample_your_controller_path(format: :xlsx), class: 
    "btn btn-smbtn-primary float-right" %>
```

I hope this will be helpful to some people.

Regards